# Java Как найти строку с максимальным количеством различных символов

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста нужно выполнить задание: "Напишите программу, где пользователь вводит сначала количество строк n, затем сами строки. Среди данных строк найти строку с максимальным количеством различных символов. Если таких строк будет много, то вывести первую".

Первую часть выполнила, а найти строку с максимальным количеством различных символов не могу понять
Мой код:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    //Ввод количества строк с клавиатуры
    System.out.println("Введите количество строк");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc1.nextInt();
    String[] str = new String[n];
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Введите строку №" + (i + 1));
        str[i] = sc2.nextLine();
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вам не нужен весь массив строк, вам нужна только строка с наибольшим количеством различных символов. Научитесь получать это количество и считай задача выполена

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти количество уникальных символов в строке, можно текущую строку (ещё в процессе чтения) преобразовать во множество символов (set), и найти наибольший размер такого множества.

Если нельзя использовать множества и другие классы (списки, хэш-таблицы) из стандартной библиотеки Collections Framework, можно завести отдельный массив чисел/булевых значений, затем заполнить этот массив для соответствующего символа текущей строки (инкремент для числа или запись `true` для булевого значения), затем посчитать количество чисел, больших 0 / или значений `true` (сразу обнуляя их), обновить при необходимости максимум / запомнить соответствующую строку с максимумом.

Реализация в коде не приводится в педагогических целях.

Comment: Массив наверное подойдёт только если там будут только буквы или  числа. Для просто символов будет сложно размер массива подобрать

Comment: Для подобного рода учебных задач как правило задаются буквы/цифры :)

Comment: да я просто привык, что если хотят решение с массивом - то явно обозначают алфавит. Но это я наверное просто перерешал задачек сам, глаз намыленный =)

Answer (score -1):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0;
    //Ввод количества строк с клавиатуры
    System.out.println("Введите количество строк");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc1.nextInt();
    String[] str = new String[n];
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Введите строку №" + (i + 1));
        str[i] = sc2.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
    int[] count = new int[n];  //Создаем массив для длин строк

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // Первый луп для итерации по элементам массива str
        for (int j = i; j < str[i].length(); j++) {
        // этот луп для того чтобы сохранить текущий символ  
            char temp = ' ';
            for (int z = j; z < str[i].length(); z++) {
            //Текущий символ в третьем лупе будет сравниваться с каждым символом в данной строке

                if (str[i].charAt(j) != str[i].charAt(z) && temp != str[i].charAt(z)) {
                // Если текущий символ не будет равен следующему символу то делаем count[]++ то есть прибавляем длину
                    temp = str[i].charAt(z);                                            
                    count[i]++;                                                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        // Ищем строку с максимальной длиной различных символов и если второй больше первого сохраняем строку
        if (max <= count[i]) {
            max = count[i];
            answer = str[i];
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println(answer);                                                   // ФИНИШ
}
```

Но можно еще `ArrayList`-ом воспользоваться и сохранить символы строк как элемент `ArrayList`, а затем воспользоваться методом `contains()`: если возвращает `false`, то прибавляем длину.

Comment: В коде есть ошибки, например, второй цикл по `j` будет пропускать символы в начале каждой строки, не учитывая их при подсчёте _разных символов_.  Да и подсчёт разных символов выглядит сомнительно.

Comment: да потом я и сам понял что есть недоработки